# Referencing $(this) inside each()

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, post, each

I am trying to generate a table with php and place it where a div has the class "accordian-table". However, the resulting html code does not replace the div when I run the code below. I am assuming that I am incorrectly referencing ".accordian-table", since a modified function without an each statement works.

```
function gettable () {
    $('.accordian-system').each( function() {

        var accordianSystem = $(this);

        var selectedID = accordianSystem.children('.selItems option:selected').val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'ajax-gettable.php',
            data: { ID: selectedID },
            success: function(data) {
                accordianSystem.find('.accordian-table' ).replaceWith(data);
            }
        });


    } );
}
```

The html structure is:

```
<div class="accordian-systems">
    <h3></h3>
    <div class="accordian-system">
        <select class="selItems"></select>
        <div class="accordian-table"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

EDIT: I guess it isn't reaching the success function. Yet it does when I replace this:

```
var selectedID = accordianSystem.children('.selItems option:selected').val();
```

with this:

```
var selectedID = $('.accordian-system').children('.selItems option:selected').val();
```

AND if remove this and its closing brace:

```
$('.accordian-system').each( function() {
```

Comment: Don't Assume, debug your code and let us know if it goes into the success function or not, also create the error call back so you know when you are having other problems.

Comment: Do you know if that ajax call is actually returning something? please show the console output of data.

Comment: [Accordion](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/accordion) ends with "*on*", not "*an*".

Comment: Add code that works to the question as well.

Answer (score 2):

This statement won't work properly:

```
accordianSystem.children('.selItems option:selected').val()
```

That is only going to match direct children that satisfy that selector, but `option:selected` is never a direct child (it's a child of a child) so it won't match anything.  I think you probably want this:

```
accordianSystem.find('.selItems option:selected').val()
```

If you could have more than one element selected, you would have to modify this code further because it could return an array of values, not just a single value.

---

Also, Luis' advice is sound.  Don't assume what your code is doing.  Set breakpoints, step through it and see what it is actually doing.  If it is not hitting your `success` handler, then create an `error` handler and look at the arguments to that to see why it is failing.  The way your code is currently written, you will probably be passing `null` as the `selectedID` until you implement the recommended change above.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sc77t/6/)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="accordian-systems">
     <h3>Accordian Systems</h3>

    <div class="accordian-system">
        <select class="selItems">
            <option selected='selected'>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
        </select>
        <div class="accordian-table"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="accordian-system">
        <select class="selItems">
            <option selected='selected'>3</option>
            <option>4</option>
        </select>
        <div class="accordian-table"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
var accordianSystems = $('div.accordian-system');
accordianSystems.each(function (index, element) {
    var selectedItemText = $(element).find('.selItems option:selected').text();
    setTable(element, selectedItemText);
});
accordianSystems.find('.selItems').change(function () {
    setTable($(this).parent(), $(this).val());
});

function setTable(accordianSystem, id) {
    $(accordianSystem).children('div.accordian-table').text('Selected value: ' + id);
    //Here you would otherwise call your ajax function...
}
```

Comment: Yes, when the accordion is loaded, I want to initially add the appropriate table to every tab.

Comment: @spooky655 updated the answer, this should work... :)

Comment: @spooky655 I updated the example, i write to console instead of calling an ajax function but you can just swap out that part.

Answer (score 0):

When the value of the `select` element changes, an ajax request is made with the value of the `select` element. The response from the ajax request replaces the div with the  `.accordian-table`  class. **What if you change the value of the select again? There is no div to replace!** I'll provide a solution that should work the first time and subsequent time.

```
$(function() {
    $('div.accordian-system').children('select.selItems').on('change', gettable);
});

function gettable () {
    var accordianSystem = $(this).parent();
    var selectedID = this.value;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'ajax-gettable.php',
        data: { ID: selectedID },
        success: function(data) {
            var repElem = accordianSystem.children('.accordian-table' ) || $(this).next();
            repElem.replaceWith(data);
        }
    });
}
```

[**This Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/wKA2g/) simply demonstrates that when the value of the `select` element changes, an ajax request is made. You can check the network tab of your debug tools and you should see something like this:

```
Remote Address:162.243.204.190:80
Request URL:http://fiddle.jshell.net/fiddleyetu/wKA2g/show/ajax-gettable.php
Request Method:POST
Status Code:404 NOT FOUND
Chrome/35.0.1916.153 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With:XMLHttpRequest
Form Dataview sourceview URL encoded
ID:50
```

Comment: I tried this, but it doesn't make it to the success function. Also, "gettable" needs "()".

Comment: The `()` will make it execute immediately. Let me put a jsfiddle together to show you it fires the ajax call ... which means you may have to work on your server returning some thing.

Comment: @spooky655, please see my updated answer, feel free to play around with the demo ... :( only we can't get an `ajax response`!